# How to get last 3 records from table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following  fields and data:

```
uid     message         created
======= =============== ==========
1       text1           1305244929
2       text2           1305244930
3       text3           1305244931
1       text4           1305244932
1       text5           1305244933
3       text6           1305244934
2       text7           1305244945
1       text8           1305244956
3       text9           1305244947
1       text10          1305244948
2       text11          1305244967
1       text12          1305244968
3       text13          1305244969
1       text14          1305244970
2       text15          1305244971
3       text16          1305244972
3       text17          1305244973
```

How to get last 3 records **for each** uid ordered DESC by created

Comment: Ideally whatever this table is should have it's own 'ID' column, keeps things relational (if you design it properly) and makes things like what you want to do easy :)

Comment: I think your table needs a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but it should do the trick:

```
SELECT uid, message, created FROM (
SELECT
IF(@prev != q.uid, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as rownumber, @prev:=q.uid, q.*
FROM (
    SELECT
    uid, message, created
    FROM yourTable yt
    , (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prev:='') r
    ORDER BY uid, created DESC
)q
)asdf
WHERE asdf.rownumber <= 3
```

And like others said, a primary key would be nice for your table.

Comment: For a big table it takes to long to receive the results. Maybe a better solution can be found

Comment: Put a combined index on (uid, created) and see if that helps. Without you changing your database schema I doubt there's another way to speed this up.

Comment: @BoiculeseIuli Have you tried putting an index on the columns? Any feedback?